# error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘>’ token

Tags: c++, dictionary, header, compiler-errors

I know there are a billion similar topics, but none of the advice I've seen in any of them has helped me solve this... this is in a file saved as header.h

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <map>

using namespace std;
class Handler {
public:
    Handler();
    ~Handler();

    bool handle(int client);
    void giveMaps(map<string, string> host, map<string,string> media>);

private:
    map<string, string> hosts;
    map<string, string> mediaLookup;
    char buf_[1600];
    char* getCurrentDate();

};
```

And my error is "handler.h:18: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘>’ token", where line 18 in the original is "void giveMaps(map host, map media>);"

I've tried declaring both the maps as const, along with all the strings inside the map, but so far I've got nothing. I'm positive it's something simple, I just need another pair of eyes to see it...

Comment: What's the extra one after `media` doing there?

Comment: Putting "using namespace std;" in a header file is a very, very bad practice which will make anybody that has to use your header file curse you forever. IF you want to use it in .cpp files, go ahead, although that's not a very good practice either. Putting it in your header files, on the other hand, means that anybody including your header file will have everything in the std namespace brought into the global namespace whether they wanted it or not (and they probably didn't). Also, be sure to make your destructor virtual if Handler is going to be used as a base class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an extra `>`. Please remove (its third last in the statement after `media`):

Updated statement should look like below:

```
void giveMaps(map<string, string> host, map<string,string> media);
```

Comment: I knew it was something simple, thanks! (feel foolish for asking the question now, but oh well, that's life...)

Comment: This is fine. Sometimes you need another pair of eyes to look at trivial things. Please don't forget to accept the answer.

Answer (score 3):

There is an extra `>` at the end of

```
void giveMaps(map<string, string> host, map<string,string> media>);
```

Answer (score 1):

As well as the other advice given, the following is incorrect:

```
#include <string.h>
```

You should drop the `.h` so you just have:

```
#include <string>
```

Comment: While he certainly should be including `string`, `string.h` is the **C** header for string manipulation and the **C++** equivalent would be `cstring`.

Comment: string.h should be included in C++ as #include <cstring>

Comment: This answer helped me debug the next issue that I saw. I wish there was a way to accept multiple answers (or that I at least had the reputation to vote this up!)

Comment: Good comment about `cstring` although I can't see that it's necessary to include it the OPs example as none of the functionality that it covers needs declared here.